# Cevians concuring and a sum.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Geometry problems that me and my squad cannot solve. This quarantine, we decided to make some geometrical research, we got stucked on this:

In a $\triangle ABC$ triangle, let the Cevians $AL$, $BM$, $CN$ concur  on a  point $O$.

Show that: $\frac{OL}{AL}+\frac{OM}{BM}+\frac{ON}{CN}=1$

I am using the Ceva equality to get that 1, but we are not sure about that. 
Also, what does this theorem mean in terms of dividing the cevians in parts ?

Any hint/solution is welcome. Thank you !
[image: figure made on Geogebra to try a better visual]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The idea is to use ratio of areas of triangle. Thus: $\dfrac{OL}{AL} = \dfrac{S_{OBC}}{S_{ABC}}$. Repeat this with the other two fractions and add up...